# Orientation to landscape works as expected in the emulator, but not on the device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-orientation

I am almost done with an app where I used the bottom navigation bar to switch between different layouts (not activities, if relevant), and with some custom layouts for landscape orientation for both phone and tablet. My app behaves as expected when I run it in the emulator, but when I export an apk to test on my device (phone in this case), the app won't switch to landscape mode at all.

Let me know if you want me to paste some parts of my code you think would be relevant - I have no idea where to start regarding this problem.

EDIT: Here are the manifest and activity files:

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".StoryListActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".StoryDetailActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_story_detail"
        android:parentActivityName=".StoryListActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.compy.someappname.StoryListActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Activity:

public class StoryListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private FrameLayout mainFrameLayout;
private FrameLayout shopFrameLayout;
private FrameLayout infoFrameLayout;

/**
 * Whether or not the activity is in two-pane mode, i.e. running on a tablet
 * device.
 */

private boolean mTwoPane;

private int visiblePart;

protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (mainFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("visiblePart", 0);
    } else if (shopFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("visiblePart", 1);
    } else if (infoFrameLayout.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("visiblePart", 2);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null){
        visiblePart = savedInstanceState.getInt("visiblePart");
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_story_list);

    mainFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainFrameLayout);
    shopFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.shopFrameLayout);
    infoFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.infoFrameLayout);
    appBarLayout = (AppBarLayout) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    TextView titleTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
    TextView titleTextView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.titleTextView2);
    Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Ovo-Regular.ttf");
    titleTextView.setTypeface(typeface);
    titleTextView2.setTypeface(typeface);

    if (visiblePart == 0) {
        mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (visiblePart == 1) {
        mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else if (visiblePart == 2) {
        mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


    BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView)
            findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
            new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.action_main:
                            mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_shop:
                            mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            break;
                        case R.id.action_info:
                            mainFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            shopFrameLayout.setVisibility(GONE);
                            infoFrameLayout.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                            break;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

    View recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.story_list);
    assert recyclerView != null;
    setupRecyclerView((RecyclerView) recyclerView);

    if (findViewById(R.id.story_detail_container) != null) {
        // The detail container view will be present only in the
        // large-screen layouts (res/values-w900dp).
        // If this view is present, then the
        // activity should be in two-pane mode.
        mTwoPane = true;
    }
}



private void setupRecyclerView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView) {
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(DummyContent.ITEMS));
}

public class SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final List<DummyContent.DummyItem> mValues;

    public SimpleItemRecyclerViewAdapter(List<DummyContent.DummyItem> items) {
        mValues = items;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.story_list_content, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mItem = mValues.get(position);
        holder.mIdView.setText(mValues.get(position).id);
        holder.mContentView.setText(mValues.get(position).story_title);


        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mTwoPane) {
                    Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
                    arguments.putString(StoryDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);
                    StoryDetailFragment fragment = new StoryDetailFragment();
                    fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.story_detail_container, fragment)
                            .commit();
                } else {
                    Context context = v.getContext();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, StoryDetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(StoryDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, holder.mItem.id);

                    context.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mValues.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View mView;
        public final TextView mIdView;
        public final TextView mContentView;
        public DummyContent.DummyItem mItem;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            mView = view;
            mIdView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id);
            mContentView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.content);
            Typeface typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Ovo-Regular.ttf");
            mIdView.setTypeface(typeface);
            mContentView.setTypeface(typeface);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return super.toString() + " '" + mContentView.getText() + "'";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Post your activity code and your androidmanifest.xml

Comment: Silly one: Is your phone's orientation portrait-locked?

Comment: silly but legit - however it is on auto rotate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
    /**
     * Getting screen orientation and ON rotation if it is OFF
     */
    private void rotationON() {
        if (Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 0) {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Getting screen orientation and Off rotation if it is ON
     */
    private void rotationOFF() {
        if (Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0) == 1) {
            Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did not break my app in the emulator, but sadly nothing changed for the device behavior

Comment: in the device setting,is it auto rotating or locked?

Comment: Remembered to check - auto rotate

Comment: other app in the device working with different orientation.

Comment: It does not! Thanks for suggesting it! Rebooted it, and worked again, but when I run this app it breaks my auto rotate for some reason

Comment: I am going to mark your answer as correct, as it seems like my device is faulty and you pointed it out. Thanks